# Locate files older than 7 days and contain the word "t" in the third char of the file name

Tags: linux, shell, find, command

I am trying to figure out how to find all the files that are older than 7 days and contain the letter "t" as the third character (of the filename).

I only figure out how to find the files that are older that 7 days:

```
find /home -mtime +7 -print
```

Comment: `contain the word "T" on their third char (of the file name)` - you mean that the 3rd letter of the filename of the file should be a __letter__ `T`? Or that the file should have a letter `T` as the 3rd byte in it's content?

Comment: I mean that the 3rd letter of the filename will be the char "t"

Answer (score 2):

To restrict to filenames having a "t" in the third position, like "25t.txt" or "data-19.doc", add this clause:

```
-name "??t*"
```

to the command. `-name` looks only the base name, i.e. with the path removed.

Answer (score 1):

You need to specialize your find with a regex in this way:

```
find /home -mtime +7 -regextype posix-extended -regex '^.*\/.{2}T.*' -print
```

Explanation of the command:
You add a regular expression that filter all the result of the find for the first N character before the "/" character and after the "/" character have at third position the character "T". You need the first part of the regular expression ( `^.*\/` ) because the find return the result with fullpath so in the form ***"./dir/dir1/filename.extension"***. The last part of regular espression is to filter all the file with extension.

Annotation: you can substitute "T" with character you want.